# PHP: Is there a better way to apply a function to a variable and assign it at the same time?

Tags: php, variable-assignment

This question may seem a bit strange - maybe the answer is simpl no - but it bothers me. If I apply a function to a variable *why do I have to write its name twice*?

Is there something like apply and assign at the same time?

Example:

```
function abc($cat_id) {
    $cat_id = intval($cat_id);
    return $cat_id * $cat_id;
}
```

I would like:

```
function abc($cat_id) {
    intval($cat_id); // and apply the new value, but without writing an extra function
    return $cat_id * $cat_id;
}
```

A pseudo code example of what I am searching for would be:

`intval($cat_id)<=`

... some operator like "assign result to input".

Comment: Do like this:- `function abc($cat_id) {
    return $cat_id * (intval($cat_id));
}`. Btw what ADyson said is completely correct.

Answer (score 4):

While there may be ways to do so by abusing type coercion, it is not good practice at all.

Think about what you're doing in simple steps: you're calling a function, that returns you a result, and you assign that result to a variable. Three steps, that are all shown in the code.

What you want is to hide the last step, that serves no good purposes and make the code less straightforward to follow.

Eg:

```
$a = "something"
some_cool_function($a);
```

Has `$a` changed in that function call ? You have no way to know other than inspecting the details.

It's much better to always let mutation be seen at first glance.

Comment: Sure but functions like `usort` for instance do it anyway?! If this is a short function I do not think that this behaviour does influence readibility, especially if there it is visible through a certain character.

Comment: @Blackbam usort receives the array variable by reference - see the definition in the docs. http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php. intval does not do that. So it depends on how the function is implemented. In usort's case there's a reason to do it like that - it's sensible to operate on the actual array to avoid producing a new one (could use up a lot of memory for no reason) and also it wants to return a true/false success indicator as the output. Different use case, IMO.

Comment: `usort` might be called on very large dataset and thus producing a brand new copy of it may not be the right move. But unless you have specific reasons like this, mutability should always be shown. That's why most PHP function do not behave like that if possible. Think about it: you don't have to write it two times for no reason, you have to write it two times because you do two different operations on it: 1. passing it as an argument, 2. assigning it a new value. What you ask is, "how can I hide that second operation from the reader". Why would you want that ?

Comment: Try to think of it as if 1. it wasn't your code, but you're reading someone else's code, wouldn't you prefer to know exactly when things change ? And 2. If it wasn't a simple `intval` but a much more complex function whose side effects are not very clear to the reader (see my example in the main answer), thus you don't "obviously know" that it changes the value. Like I said, mutability is one of those things that should always be clearly exposed.

Comment: Sure I agree with your point here. Still why is it a bad idea to have a single character to assign the result to the input, not hiding it. But as a consequence of this discussion I guess there is nothing like this?

Answer (score 1):

Your suggestion would work if the value was passed by reference, I think.

But what you have to do is get the output of the `intval()` function, because that's how the `intval()` function works. You could need/want to make a new variable (e.g. `$x = intval($cat_id);` ), and this syntax gives you that flexibility, whereas if you had to do it the way you suggested then it wouldn't give you the option. It would also make it a lot less clear what was happening - it wouldn't be immediately clear, apart from by inspection or reading documentation, whether `intval()` was changing the variable or not.

Your question "why do I have to write its name twice" doesn't really make much sense in my opinion. You're only writing it twice because you *chose* to. What you're actually doing is sending variable `a` into the function as the input parameter, and getting variable `b` out as the result of the function. They are different variables. `b` is newly created by `intval()` as a result of its processing, and returned to you as output.

The fact you chose to re-assign your existing `$cat_id` variable to now represent the the result of the function is *your* choice, nothing to do with the language. You could have assigned the result to another variable instead, as I mentioned above.

Comment: Sure it is a special case where I decide to re-assign the result. But whats bad about having something like `&=intval($cat_id)` or `intval($cat_id)<=` (just ideas). I wonder if there is something like that.

Comment: well you could just do `return intval($cat_id) * intval($cat_id);` if you wanted. In that particular case it means you end up doing the conversion twice, but again it's circumstantial since you happen to be multiplying the number by itself. In this specific case your existing code is more efficient to execute, even if it's a tiny bit more verbose to write.

Comment: If you were multiplying two different numbers, e.g. `return intval($cat_id) * intval($x);` then that would be resonable way to write it. But note that the multiplication is done on the _outputs of intval()_, not on the original variables. After that multiplication operation completed, `$cat_id` and `$x` would still be strings (actually, technically in this case they cease to exist, since the function returns immediately, but the point is that those variables were not themselves mutated into ints - instead, new variables were created by `intval()` and returned to the multiplication operator).

Answer (score 1):

You can do instead

```
function abc($cat_id) {
    return (int)$cat_id * (int)$cat_id;
}
```

Comment: Thanks but this works only for this particular case, I was looking for a more general way.

Comment: Write a function that does what you want `function myintval(&$var){ $var=intval($var); }`

Comment: Not exactly what I want but you have initiated a nice idea.

Answer (score -1):

Well I found a solution - you may hate it, but it does what I want, even for multiple functions:

```
/**
 * Apply 1..n one parameter functions to the given variable.
 *
 * @param array/mixed $callback: An array of Callback functions which accept one parameter.
 * @param $var: The variable to apply them to.
 */
function §($callback,&$var) {
    if(is_array($callback)) {
        foreach($callback as $c) {
            $var = $c($var);
        }
    } else {
        $var = $callback($var);
    }
}

$a = "4";

§('intval',$a);

var_dump($a);

§(['intval','exp','ceil'],$a);

var_dump($a);
```

Result:

> int(4)
>
> float(55)